# Using APPIUM to test apps (not Safari) on a real iPhone device

Tags: iphone, appium

I'm investigating the possibility of using Appium to test our product on iPhone, so I don't have it installed yet (and I also don't have a MAC).

I found a question asking basically this, but the answer was based around launching Safari - does this also work with other applications (like calculator etc...)? 
Also, if I'm running the tests against a real device, do I still need to run them from a MAC or would a Windows PC work just as well (since handling the native app is no longer being done on the pc)?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Mac and XCode installed on it.

Appium uses the Apple UIAutomator to talk to the iOS app elements be it on simulator or real device.

UIAutomator is part of XCode, and that can be only installed on Apple hardware (there might be hacks online to install it on Windows, but the short answer is no)